# How to ask user for file Path in Java

Tags: java, file, path, qr-code

I actually have to do a program which create a QR Code with some information.
To generate it, I use a html/JavaScript interface who call a java function.
For now, I use a specific path, but I want the user to choose where I want to save it.

The question is, how can I ask the user where to save the file?

(I'm actually new in java so any advice is good :) )

Here is the function:

```
public static void generateQrcode(String check) throws WriterException, IOException
{
    try {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        String str = "qr-code-" + uuid.toString();
        String path = "/qr-code/" + str + ".png";
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        Map<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
        qrcode(check, path, charset, 250, 250);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred : " + e);
    }
}
```

```
public static void qrcode(String data, String path, String charset, int h, int w) throws WriterException, IOException
{
    BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(new String(data.getBytes(charset), charset), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, w, h);
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(path));
}
```

I tried to use the File() method, but I think it doesn't help me.

Comment: Ask first, How use this application ? 1. use a console / terminal ? or others ? You can search `java-qrcode-terminal` in github to find example code. 2. how to process input ? if your application use console / terminal, you can run like `java myaap  /home/demo/data/qrcode-uuid.png` , pass save file path as appication parameter, or `java myapp`, in your java main, use `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` , 
`String qrcodePath = reader.readLine();`

Comment: or you can save qrcode file to temp folder `/tmp/xxxxx.png`, and try to convert png file show like text char in terminal, like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alishtory/qrcode-terminal/master/example/cmdqrcode.jpg

Comment: You say your GUI is implemented with HTML/JavaScript. Then use this to ask the user for the file path and pass it to the Java function.